# stop audio to play when data is changed

Tags: javascript, firebase, audio, firebase-realtime-database

I create simple `addEventListener` audio, the idea is if my temp more than 40 C, sound will play, and if less than 40 C it will stop. But, when I try to run, it will play multiple time. For example, if 12:12:12 my temp 41, and 12:12:13 my temp is 50, it will play audio twice. How I can play just one audio in single time? And how I can pause or stop my audio to stop when temp is less tan 40 C ?
I combine this `addEventListener` with firebase database

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    firebase.database().ref('sensor').limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(data) {
        var sensor = data.val();
        console.log("suhu gauge is :"+sensor.temp)
        if (sensor.temp > 40 ) {
            myAudio = new Audio('audio/alarm.mp3'); 
            myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                this.play();
            }, false);
            myAudio.play()
        }
        else if (sensor.temp < 40 ){
            myAudio = new Audio('audio/alarm.mp3'); 
            myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                this.pause();
            }, false);
        }
        mydata.setValue(0, 1, sensor.temp);
        chart.draw(mydata, myoptions);
        console.log(sensor.temp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean Degrees Celsius with "C"?

Comment: Why do you call `.play()` again within `ended` event handler?

Comment: You remove `this.play();` in `ended` handler and if you want to pause audio then used `.pause();` event `if temp < 40`

Comment: @guest271314 because this sound must continues play when temp more than 40, and it must stop when temp less than 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `myAudio` and `ended` event handlers outside of asynchronous function, remove `this.play()` from within `ended` event handler, use `HTMLMediaElement` `.paused` and `.ended` properties to determine if media is paused or playing

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    myAudio = new Audio('audio/alarm.mp3'); 
    myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
    }, false);
    firebase.database().ref('sensor').limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(data) {
        var sensor = data.val();
        console.log("suhu gauge is :"+sensor.temp)
        if (sensor.temp > 40 ) {
            if (myAudio.paused || myAudio.ended) {
              myAudio.play()
            }
        }
        else if (sensor.temp < 40 ) {
            if (!myAudio.paused) {
              myAudio.pause();
            }
        }
        mydata.setValue(0, 1, sensor.temp);
        chart.draw(mydata, myoptions);
        console.log(sensor.temp);
    });
});
```

Comment: i replace my code with your code, but it only play once and end, the idea is still same with my old code, this sound must continues play until my temp lower than 40. but i appreciate your code..

Comment: Have you tried setting `.loop` property of `Audio` instance to `true`?

Comment: @IndoEntertain That appears to be the same pattern. Not entirely certain about logic of `if..else`. Does the JavaScript render expected result?